# Subtract values of a single row from all relevant columns in a data frame

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

I have the following data set:

```
foo=data.frame(index=rep(1:10,3),
               type=rep(c("A","B","C"),each=10),
               ping=rnorm(30),
               pong=runif(30))
```

I want to subtract the values of the columns `ping` and `pong` for `index==5` and `type=="B"`, to the whole columns `ping` and `pong`.
This works:

```
vec=matrix(subset(foo,index==5 & type=="B",select=ping:pong),2,1)
foo[,c("ping","pong")]=foo[,c("ping","pong")]-vec
```

However, I'm surprised that I had to specify `vec` as a column vector, instead than a row vector. I would have thought that I would need to subtract the same row vector to all (similar subsets of the) rows of `foo`. Can you explain why this is? Also, if the same result can be obtained with a simpler or cleaner code, please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to do this:

```
myselect <- with(foo, index ==5 & type == "B")
mycol <- c('ping','pong')

foo[, mycol] <- foo[, mycol] - as.list(foo[myselect, mycol])
```

`vec` should be a list, as substraction of lists is done element by element. That is what you want, and that is also what you're doing actually:

First of all, you don't specify `vec` as a matrix. if you use `matrix()` instead of `as.matrix()` on a list, you get a list. And as a data frame is essentially a list, `matrix()` gives you a list back with an attribute "dim". That attribute makes it look like a matrix, but:

```
> str(vec)
List of 2
 $ : num 0.704
 $ : num 0.164
 - attr(*, "dim")= int [1:2] 2 1
```

What you use here, is a side effect of the function `matrix()`. It also drops other attributes, so it removes the `data.frame` information of `vec` and makes it a list. If `vec` would still be a data frame, it wouldn't work. You can only use a mathematical operator when both data frames have the same size. And this is not the case here.

```
> vec=subset(foo,index==5 & type=="B",select=ping:pong)
> foo[,c("ping","pong")]-vec
Error in Ops.data.frame(foo[, c("ping", "pong")], vec) : 
  ‘-’ only defined for equally-sized data frames
```

You also shouldn't make it a matrix. If you do, R will recycle your matrix and your dataframe column-wise. That means it substracts the first value of vec from the first of foo$ping, the second value of vec from the second of foo$ping, the first value of vec again from the third value of foo$ping and so forth. It doesn't matter in which direction you put the matrix, it's always the same (wrong!) result:

```
mytest<- matrix(c(-10,10), nrow = 1)
mytest2 <- t(mytest)
myfoo <- foo[,c('ping','pong')]
all.equal(myfoo - mytest, myfoo - mytest2)
```

Comment: Thanks! Thus, my solution works because it doesn't do what I thought it would do. However, I could reasonably be excused for expecting that a function called `matrix`, whose help doc starts with `matrix creates a matrix from the given set of values`, would actually return a matrix ;)

Comment: @DeltaIV yeah, I have to admit that some things in R make me scratch my head as well :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do the following.

```
Map(`-`, foo[, c("ping", "pong")], 
    subset(foo, index == 5 & type == "B")[, c("ping", "pong")])
```

This returns list but you can convert to `data.frame` by `as.data.frame()`.

`Map` takes a function and a set of vectors and apply the function element-wise.  Note that `-` is the subtract function.  In this example `Map` is given two `data.frame` objects, whose elements are columns.  Hence this `Map` operation conducts column-by-column subtraction.

For more details see [Advanced R page](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functionals.html#functionals)

Comment: Hey, cool! I didn't know about `Map`. I appreciate the info. However, I'm choosing @Joris Meys answer which is a bit more readable, and also explains what's happening "behind the scenes"  with my approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do something like this:

```
foo$ping <- foo$ping - foo[foo$index == 5 & foo$type == 'B', 'ping']
foo$pong <- foo$pong - foo[foo$index == 5 & foo$type == 'B', 'pong']
```

If you have multiple rows that match `index == 5` and `type == 'B'`, you may need to wrap the part being subtracted in some function like `min`, `max` or `mean` that gives a single value.

To answer your question, you are trying to subtract a 2x1 matrix from each row in a data frame's column, which is the same as subtracting two pairs of values row wise. You can try this and see it works since both are vectors:

```
x <- c(10, 20)
y <- c(5, 10)
x
[1] 10 20
y
[1]  5 10
x - y
[1]  5 10
```

Whereas this won't work as it will apply the second vector on rows repeatedly (1 and 2):

```
df <- data.frame(x = rep(10, 10), y = rep(5, 10))
df
    x y
1  10 5
2  10 5
3  10 5
4  10 5
5  10 5
6  10 5
7  10 5
8  10 5
9  10 5
10 10 5
df - c(10, 5)
   x  y
1  0 -5
2  5  0
3  0 -5
4  5  0
5  0 -5
6  5  0
7  0 -5
8  5  0
9  0 -5
10 5  0
```

Whereas, operating it on row by row basis like this works although it is much slower since it loops:

```
df <- sapply(df, function(x) x - c(10, 5))
      x  y
 [1,] 0 -5
 [2,] 5  0
 [3,] 0 -5
 [4,] 5  0
 [5,] 0 -5
 [6,] 5  0
 [7,] 0 -5
 [8,] 5  0
 [9,] 0 -5
[10,] 5  0
```

Comment: He's not using a matrix but a list. Convert your c(10,5) to a matrix and try again. You still get the same (wrong) result. See also my post for a more elaborate explanation on why vec is a list in his code, and why it should be.