# Add/subtract data frame row from another data frame r

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I'm having a hard time finding it. I need to subset a data frame to a single row and subtract those values from the corresponding columns.

I actually did find [Subtract values of a single row from all relevant columns in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35036641/subtract-values-of-a-single-row-from-all-relevant-columns-in-a-data-frame), which provided a solution (see below), but there has to be a simpler way, right? A `tidyverse` solution would be most appreciated.

## Sample

Here is a sample data frame:

```
df <- as_tibble(matrix(1:9, 3, 3))
## A tibble: 3 x 3
#     V1    V2    V3
#  <int> <int> <int>
#1     1     4     7
#2     2     5     8
#3     3     6     9
```

Subtracting equal sized data frames is no problem.

```
df - df
#  V1 V2 V3
#1  0  0  0
#2  0  0  0
#3  0  0  0
```

## Problem

But when I subset `df` to one row and try to subtract, it is unable to subtract uneven data frames. I subset `df` as

```
df[1, ]
## A tibble: 1 x 3
#     V1    V2    V3
#  <int> <int> <int>
#1     1     4     7
```

My desired solution will subtract 1 from each value in the first column, 4 from each value in the second and 7 from each in the third, such that this is the result:

```
## A tibble: 3 x 3
#     V1    V2    V3
#  <int> <int> <int>
#1     0     0     0
#2     1     1     1
#3     2     2     2
```

Trying this results in an error:

```
df - df[1, ]
#Error in Ops.data.frame(df, df[1, ]) : 
#  ‘-’ only defined for equally-sized data frames
```

In the link above, I found this solution, which works:

```
as_tibble(Map(`-`, df, df[1, ]))
## A tibble: 3 x 3
#     V1    V2    V3
#  <int> <int> <int>
#1     0     0     0
#2     1     1     1
#3     2     2     2
```

But this solution seems really complicated and isn't easily incorporated into a series of pipes.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Your last line `isn't easily incorporated into a series of pipes`.  How do you want the solution to look like?

Comment: @akrun The preferred method would be something like `df %>% mutate(. - slice(1))` . Something like that. I'd like to use `mutate` or a variant like `mutate_all`.

Comment: Ok, I added another solution below, please check

Comment: @akrun Now you're just showing off. Ha! Thanks for the great variety.

Comment: I didn't know what your expectations are.  So, I am giving other varieties as well.

Comment: You can use `df %>% mutate_at(2:3, list(~ . - first(.)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can replicate the row base don the `col` index of dataset.  This makes both the datasets to have same length/dimension

```
df - unlist(df[1,])[col(df)]
#   V1 V2 V3
#1  0  0  0
#2  1  1  1
#3  2  2  2
```

---

if we need a tidyverse option, `map2` can be used

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map2_df(df, df[1, ], `-`)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#     V1    V2    V3
#  <int> <int> <int>
#1     0     0     0
#2     1     1     1
#3     2     2     2
```

Or another option is `uncount`

```
df - uncount(df[1, ], nrow(df))
```

---

Or using pipe

```
df %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  uncount(nrow(df)) %>%
  {df - .}
#  V1 V2 V3
#1  0  0  0
#2  1  1  1
#3  2  2  2
```

---

Or with `mutate_all`

```
df %>%
    mutate_all(list(~ . - first(.)))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#     V1    V2    V3
#  <int> <int> <int>
#1     0     0     0
#2     1     1     1
#3     2     2     2
```

Comment: In case you're interested, I ran a benchmark test on all the variants you provided with a thousand row test df. `map2` was the fastest, closely followed by `Map`. The rest were pretty well behind.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to subtract the first row of a data.frame, then it's better to think about just subtracting the first value from each column. You can do that easily with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate_all(~.-first(.))
```